# Spring Maven Controller can't find my JSP pages

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, templates

I'm new to Spring + MVN. 
I have right now a project with a Controller and I want to "connect" with JSP page. Here you have the Project Structure:

[image: Project Structure]

I have Web-servlet.xml which contains:

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation = "
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package = "com.ms.TicketsSystem" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property> </bean>
</beans>
```

And web.xml:

```
<web-app id = "WebApp_ID" version = "2.4"
         xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Form Handling</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/add")
    public String addTicket(){
        /*
        TODO
         */
        return "add";
    }
}
```

And when I go to `localhost:8080/add` it is showing

```
Error resolving template [add], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Template Resolver error suggests using Thymeleaf. Unless it was your intention to use it, try disabling it in your application properties file by using `spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false`

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! :) I will try to do it when I'm at home. I will inform you if it works.